# dh: unable to load addon config-package

Tags: debian, package, cpan, debian-jessie, debian-stretch

After installing the debuild toolchain with:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential lintian
```

I got the following error when running `debuild` to build a package:

```
dh clean  --with=config-package
dh: unable to load addon config-package: Can't locate Debian/Debhelper/Sequence/config_package.pm in @INC
(you may need to install the Debian::Debhelper::Sequence::config_package module) (@INC contains: ...) at (eval 12) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 12) line 2.

debian/rules:22: recipe for target 'clean' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing the package `config-package-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install config-package-dev
```